# sum columns in sql depending on condition

Tags: sql

I want to sum column values depending on the following condition

```
 USERID | QUERYID | UPVOTE | DOWNVOTE
   1    | 15      | 1      |  0
   0    | 15      | 0      | -1
   6    | 15      | 0      | -1
   1    | 7       | 1      |  0 
   8    | 7       | 1      |  0
```

I'm interested to get a result for this requirement like
for `QUERYID = 15` it should return me -1 as (SUM(UPVOTE) + SUM(DOWNVOTE))
and for `QUERYID = 7` it should give me 2 by using logic same as above.
I've tried with following way

`select (SUM(UPVOTE)+ SUM(DOWNVOTE)) as "TOTAL" from "MY_TABLE" where "QUERYID" in (15, 7)';` 
But is giving me sum of all columns with the combined result of both queryId.

Comment: add     GROUP BY query_id;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `group by` clause to generate a separate result per unique value of `queryid`:

```
SELECT   (SUM(upvote) + SUM(downvote)) AS "TOTAL"
FROM     mytable
-- Possibly also add a where clause here if you only want to do this for some queryids
GROUP BY queryid
```

Comment: I've multiple QueryId's not single queryId

Comment: @PrasannaSasne that's where `group by` comes in to play - it applies the aggregation per unique **value** of `queryid`. With this query you'd get one row in the result that sums the upvotes and downvotes for all the rows with `queryid=7` and one row with `queryid=15`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `group by`:

```
SELECT 
    "QUERYID",
    (SUM(UPVOTE)+ SUM(DOWNVOTE)) as "TOTAL" 
FROM
    "MY_TABLE" 
WHERE 
    "QUERYID" in (15, 7)
GROUP BY 
    "QUERYID";
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed the group by clause.

```
    select QUERYID, (SUM(UPVOTE)+ SUM(DOWNVOTE)) as TOTAL 
      from MY_TABLE where QUERYID in (15, 7)
 GROUP BY QUERYID;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select QUERYID, (SUM(UPVOTE)+ SUM(DOWNVOTE)) as "TOTAL" from "MY_TABLE" GROUP BY QUERYID
```

Try this code, and let me know what happend

Comment: I've multiple query Id's

Comment: IT WILL DISPLAY sum for ALL AND IF YOU WANT TO RESTRICT TO THE SPECIFIC ONE THEN ADD WHERE CLAUSE